# Connecting to pins on USB to Serial module (contains FT232RL chip)

Tags: uart, rs232, pins, ftdi

I have this module:

[image]

My question pertains specifically to the RX and TX pins shown (sorry for having it upside down, only way I could make it look clear.)

I don't understand why there are 4 pins, for 2 signals. I would like to use this module to send information to my FPGA (DE0-nano), using an IP core that implements UART-RS232. However I do not know how to connect the two.

If some of those pins are ground, how do I know which ones? It is not labeled.

This thing was originally used to program a PIC through the computer, by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a part or model number for the module?

Comment: Can't you just trace where the pins are connected?

Comment: No I do not have any information about the module.

 I think I just solved it. I connect a jumper to activate the connection between the 2 pins, to use RX or TX. Ground is available in 3 of the 28 sockets that the PIC would normally be embedded into.

Comment: If you have the solution, you are encouraged to post it as an answer your own question.  It'll help future answer-seekers, plus it'll give people the opportunity to upvote the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it out:

I connect a jumper to activate the connection between the 2 pins, to use RX or TX. Ground is available in 3 of the 28 sockets that the PIC would normally be embedded into.